# horizontal scrolling react photo gallery

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use the reakt photo gallery library; my component gets an array of images as props and converts it into an array of objects with fields {src, width, height}. Everything works well, but the problem is that I have a specific height for the block, into which the gallery should be inserted. the height of the block is significantly less than the height of the entire block of the gallery, so I assumed that the pictures would scroll horizontally, and they still continue to scroll vertically, how can I make a horizontal scroll?

```
import React from 'react';
import Gallerys from 'react-photo-gallery';

const Content = styled.div`
  height: 700px;
  width: auto;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  img {
    border-radius:10px;
}
`;

class Gallery extends React.Component {

 render() {
   return (
     <Content>
       <Gallerys direction={'row'} margin={40} photos={images} />
     </Content>
   );
  }
 }

 export default Gallery;
```

Answer (score 2):

please check the answer here https://codesandbox.io/embed/lively-sun-zqe7g

> Note: Use this in your style.css/ style.scss

```
//use in css
.react-photo-gallery--gallery div {
  flex-flow: nowrap !important;
}


//use in sass/scss
.react-photo-gallery--gallery{
  div{
    flex-flow: nowrap !important;
  }
}
```